# How to use Lombok in jshell?

Tags: java, lombok, jshell

How I can use Lombok annotation in JShell?

I tried

```
* jshell --class-path lombok.jar
jshell> import lombok.*
jshell> @Data class Person { String name; String address; }
|  created class Person
jshell> new Person()
$3 ==> Person@6f7fd0e6
jshell> $3.setName("Hi")
|  Error:
|  cannot find symbol
|    symbol:   method setName(java.lang.String)
|  $3.setName("Hi")
|  ^--------^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work.  JShell doesn't support annotation processors as would be needed to make the Lombok annotations to work as you are expecting.

See [JDK-8213600 - JShell compilation does not take Lombok's annotation processor into account](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8213600)

---

For a workaround, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74084467/139985 or the bug report itself.

Basically, you need to compile the Lombok code outside of jshell, and then import the compiled classes into your jshell session.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible as described by [this bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8213600).

The workaround that is mentioned there is to compile your class externally. For that, you basically have to follow the following steps:

1. Create some directory, e.g. `com/example`.
2. Put the `Person` class below in that directory.

```java
package com.example;

import lombok.*;

@Data
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

3. Compile the class with:

```bash
javac -cp lombok.jar com/example/Person.java
```

4. Create an archive with:

```bash
jar -cf person.jar com/
```

5. Run JShell:

```bash
jshell --class-path "person.jar:lombok.jar"
```

6. Create a `Person`:

```
> import com.example.*;
> var p = new Person();
```

Also note that JShell cannot access classes that are in the default package (as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/jshell/external-code.htm)) which is why we put `Person` in `com.example`.